# Call latency (lag / quality) conference vs client call with Twilio

Tags: twilio

For our VoIP-application (customer care) I'm using the Twilio Voice API. Im using conference calls in order to implement features such as warm-transfer, (on/off) hold, queues etc.. However, we get some complains that there is a delay when an agent is speaking to a customer. This delay is noticeable and a bit annoying. The strange is that all the online / hardware tests etc are saying that the connection is just fine.

As a test I used Client calling instead of a conference call, and the quality was much better and the delay was barely noticeable. Also the voice quality was much better. How is this possible? I think the quality of conference are calls less then client calls?

I am willing to drop conference calling and stick with client calls only. Is it, using client calls, still possible to hold / un hold a customer during a call? And how can I implement warm-transfers without using conference calling?

Regards,

Marcel

Comment: Where are you conference calls taking place? Have you tried turning on the Global Conference feature in your account?

Comment: All in the same country (the Netherlands). I haven't tried turning on global conference. Will that make a difference if the calls are taking place in the same country?

Comment: It will, otherwise conference calls will go via servers in the US. With global conference, the media only needs to travel to the nearest server.

Comment: Thanks. Just checked and just noticed that global conference is already turned on.

Comment: In that case I would probably raise this with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with some example call sids if possible, and see whether they can discover the root of your latency issues.

Comment: Thanks, just submitted a support ticket..

Comment: @MarcelVandeWeerd any followup?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I was unable to get rid of the delay with Twilio. Already had a talk with their support, but it seemed like they where unable to solve the matter. I think it is because to closest server from the Netherlands (in Ireland) is still too far away to have high-quality conversations.. We ran some tests with Zendesk Voice, I know they are using Twilio with Conference as well, and we experienced the same delay. Ended up with Plivo (Twilio alternative with a server in Londen), and the conference quality is much much better with almost no delay or lag..

Comment: Appreciate the response, thank you.